# A diferença entre Lago e Lagoa!

Tags: português-brasileiro

Lagoa e lago tem diferenças?

Procurando na internet parece-me que um deles, o lago, pode ser maior e mais natural. Está correto?

Comment: Por favor, procura essas coisas no Houaiss, por exemplo: https://www.dicio.com.br/lagoa/ lagoa é algo pequeno, lago é maior, segundo esse mesmo dicionário.

Comment: Que dicionário bom! Não conhecia! Obrigado.

Comment: Majid, tens [aqui](https://portuguese.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/304/quais-dicion%c3%a1rios-de-portugu%c3%aas-brasileiro-s%c3%a3o-confi%c3%a1veis) links a vários dicionários. Muitas vezes é bom ver mais do que um.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Acho que a resposta deste link pode ajudar bastante: https://super.abril.com.br/mundo-estranho/qual-e-a-diferenca-entre-um-lago-e-uma-lagoa/

Segue um trecho abaixo:

> A primeira diferença está no tamanho. Ambos são definidos como uma
>   extensão de água cercada por terra mas os lagos são maiores. O
>   problema é que não existem dimensões mínimas ou máximas para cada um
>   deles, o que pode gerar confusões. Existe outra diferença relacionada
>   à origem de sua formação. “Os lagos geralmente são resultados de
>   transformações em larga escala do relevo terrestre”, afirma o geógrafo
>   Mário de Biasi, da Universidade de São Paulo (USP). A maioria dos
>   lagos atuais nasceu durante as glaciações do período Pleistoceno
>   (entre 1,6 milhão e 10 mil anos atrás), quando boa parte da Terra
>   ficava coberta de gelo. O lento deslocamento das geleiras abria
>   grandes depressões no solo, onde a água se acumulava. Isso explica a
>   alta concentração de lagos no hemisfério norte (zona bastante afetada
>   pela glaciação), como os Grandes Lagos, na fronteira entre os Estados
>   Unidos e o Canadá.
>
> Outra possibilidade é a elevação de montanhas, como a cordilheira dos
>   Andes, que deu origem ao lago Titicaca, na fronteira entre Peru e
>   Bolívia. Já as lagoas costumam ser resultado de fenômenos localizados.
>   “Um desmoronamento ou mesmo um único castor podem formar uma lagoa”,
>   diz Mário. Como não existem limites precisos para diferenciar um do
>   outro, os termos geram confusão e, no final, a escolha do nome depende
>   mais do uso popular. Um bom exemplo é a lagoa dos Patos, no Rio Grande
>   do Sul – apesar de ser a maior do Brasil, ela não é chamada de lago.

Comment: Doulgas, poderia copiar o texto do link para a tua resposta e colocar como citacão. Isso evita de perdermos algo se o link quebrar.

Comment: editado! @Peixoto

Answer (score 0):

Geralmente, considera-se que a lagoa é menor, mais localizada, enquanto o lago é maior e mais abrangente. Além disso, estima-se que os lagos sejam de origem antiga, ligada a eventos geológicos, como as eras glaciais, enquanto a formação de lagoas é mais específica e aparentemente “banal..

Comment: Bem-vindo ao site, Valderi00! No Portuguese StackExchange, tentam-se usar referências, preferencialmente boas, para fortalecer a resposta, pois uma resposta sem referências tem pouquíssima força do que se tivesse, estando a tua resposta 100% correta ou não. Um exemplo de resposta com força equivalente é “a diferença entre lago e lagoa é que de lago se bebe, em lagoa se nada”. Agradeço-te pela contribuição de qualquer modo.